# How to return Multiple Recordset from Oracle Stored Procedure using single SYS_REFCURSOR

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, recordset

Is returning multiple recordset using a single cursor possible in Oracle stored procedure?

Consider an Oracle procedure

```
create or replace PROCEDURE MyProc (p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS 
BEGIN 
OPEN p_recordset FOR
  SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME FROM HR.EMPLOYEES;
  SELECT DEPARTMENT_NAME from HR.DEPARTMENTS;
END MyProc;
```

I know that the above code does not work (or probably is stupid) and that we can use 2 reference cursor to return the recordsets separately, but that is not what I need.

Also I am aware that the above is possible in MSSQL server. Is there any way we can achieve this in Oracle?

Note: If admin is marking this as duplicate, please share the link where this is already answered

Comment: No, you cannot do that with one cursor.

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't declare multiple `OUT` parameters?

Comment: Yes, I cannot declare multiple OUT params (for reasons I cannot disclose). Also, why is there an "OracleDataReader.NextResult Method"? [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledatareader.nextresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx]

Comment: @RR02 - That link does not appear to be valid.  Normally, the database framework that the client application handles the mapping of the `OUT` parameters more or less transparently.  I would expect `NextResult` to start fetching from the next `OUT sys_refcursor` parameter.  If you are prevented from declaring multiple `OUT` parameters, you cannot have multiple resultsets.  You could union the two results (after ensuring that you're returning the same number and type of columns in both) but then the client would have to know how to figure out which result is which.

Comment: @Justin Cave - Thanks for the detailed response. Will give a try to using multiple ref cursors and using the NextResult method to actually what happens... Consider your comment as voted helpful! :)

Answer (score 1):

As a (fairly stupid) workaround you could do this one:

```
OPEN p_recordset FOR
  SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, NULL AS DEPARTMENT_NAME FROM HR.EMPLOYEES
  UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL, NULL, DEPARTMENT_NAME from HR.DEPARTMENTS;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this is not what I was looking for. Had seen union and join workaround elsewhere too :)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for